# Cannot figure Async/Await and Promises to work

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise, async-await

I'm trying to learn about `async`/`await` and Promise functions. However after a lot of effort and research, I cannot find any simple way to get a proper way to use my 4 for loops.

I give you the code how it's supposed to be if Javascript if it wouldn't be asynchronous. Can you tell me where (and how) can I put promises to get my code to work as intended?

```
function (courses) {
    var lines = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
        var course = courses[i];
        var sessions = course.sessions;
        var students = course.students;
        var skills = course.skills;
        console.log('\nCourse : ' + course);

        for (var j = 0; j < sessions.length; j++) {
            var session = sessions[j];
            console.log('\nSession : ' + session);

                for (var k = 0; k < students.length; k++) {
                    var student = students[k];
                    console.log('\nStudent : ' + student);

                    for (var l = 0; l < skills.length; l++) {
                        var skill = skills[l];
                        console.log('\nSkill : ' + skill);
                        Evaluation.findOne({
                            student_id: student._id,
                            session_id: session._id,
                            skill_id: skill._id
                        }).exec(function (err, eval) {
                            console.log('\nStudentID : ' + eval);
                            console.log('\nSessionID : ' + eval);
                            console.log('\nSkillID : ' + eval);
                            console.log('\nEval : ' + eval);
                            var line = [];
                            line.push(course.name);
                            line.push(session.date);
                            line.push(student.firstname);
                            line.push(student.name);
                            if (eval) {
                                line.push(eval.name);
                                line.push(eval.mark);
                            }
                            else {
                                line.push(skill.name);
                                line.push('Not Evaluated');
                            }
                            lines.push(line)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: In your case, what you might do is create an array of promises. So inside of your 4th loop you push the promise to an array. Then, after your loops you await Promise.all(promisesArray); And there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use mongoose, all you need to change is replacing

> ```
> Evaluation.findOne({
>     student_id: student._id,
>     session_id: session._id,
>     skill_id: skill._id
> }).exec(function (err, eval) {
>     console.log('\nStudentID : ' + eval);
>     console.log('\nSessionID : ' + eval);
>     console.log('\nSkillID : ' + eval);
>     console.log('\nEval : ' + eval);
>     var line = [];
>     line.push(course.name);
>     line.push(session.date);
>     line.push(student.firstname);
>     line.push(student.name);
>     if (eval) {
>         line.push(eval.name);
>         line.push(eval.mark);
>     } else {
>         line.push(skill.name);
>         line.push('Not Evaluated');
>     }
>     lines.push(line)
> })
> ```

by

```
const eval = await Evaluation.findOne({
//           ^^^^^
    student_id: student._id,
    session_id: session._id,
    skill_id: skill._id
});
console.log('\nStudentID : ' + eval);
console.log('\nSessionID : ' + eval);
console.log('\nSkillID : ' + eval);
console.log('\nEval : ' + eval);
var line = [];
line.push(course.name);
line.push(session.date);
line.push(student.firstname);
line.push(student.name);
if (eval) {
    line.push(eval.name);
    line.push(eval.mark);
} else {
    line.push(skill.name);
    line.push('Not Evaluated');
}
lines.push(line)
```

as all methods return promise-like objects already that you can directly `await`, instead of using `exec` and passing a nodeback.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do two things here: you want to asynchronously loop through courses/sessions/students/skills and do a fairly time-intensive `Evaluation.findOne` call.

I recommend replacing some or all of your for loops with `async.forEach`. You could also put the `Evaluation.findOne` block into a helper function wrapped in a `Promise`, but given that it's pushed into `lines` after it's executed it's an optional move.

Do something like this:  the skills iteration now uses async.forEach and the line builder is in a promise.

```
function (courses) {
    var lines = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
        var course = courses[i];
        var sessions = course.sessions;
        var students = course.students;
        var skills = course.skills;
        console.log('\nCourse : ' + course);
        for (var j = 0; j < sessions.length; j++) {
            var session = sessions[j];
            console.log('\nSession : ' + session);
            for (var k = 0; k < students.length; k++) {
                var student = students[k];
                console.log('\nStudent : ' + student);
                skills.forEach(function(skill) {
                    console.log('\nSkill : ' + skill);
                    buildStudentLine(student, session, skill, course)
                        .then((line )=> {
                            lines.push(line);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        })

                });
            }
        }
    }
    return lines;
}


function buildStudentLine(student, session, skill, course) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Evaluation
        .findOne({
            student_id: student._id,
            session_id: session._id,
            skill_id: skill._id
        })
        .exec(function (err, evaluated) {
            var line = [];
            line.push(course.name);
            line.push(session.date);
            line.push(student.firstname);
            line.push(student.name);
            if (evaluated) {
                line.push(evaluated.name);
                line.push(evaluated.mark);
            } else {
                line.push(skill.name);
                line.push('Not Evaluated');
                // possibly put this in here if you don't want the line to enter the lines array:
                // reject('Not Evaluated');
            }
            resolve(line);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You're not using the `async.js` library in your code anywhere? (Which is good, since it wouldn't work well with the promises)